# find all albums by ids + find all non-private how to?

Tags: cakephp

I search for all albums by `id` using:

```
$this->Album->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Album.id' => $albums_ids,
        'Album.galleries_id' => $id
    )
));
```

But I also would like to find all non-private albums (`private == 0`) *as well*. I tried:

```
$this->Album->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Album.id' => $albums_ids,
        'Album.galleries_id' => $id,
        'OR'=> array(
            array('Album.private' => 0),
            array('Album.galleries_id' => $id)
        )
    )
));
```

but no success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be gallery_id

> ```
> $this->Album->find('all', array(
> 'conditions' => array(
>     'Album.galleries_id' => $id,
>     'OR'=> array(
>         'Album.private' => 0,
>         'Album.id' => $albums_ids
>     )
> )
> ```
>
> ));

Answer (score 0):

Would you not simply be looking for the following logic instead?

```
$this->Album->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Album.id' => $albums_ids,
        'Album.galleries_id' => $id,
        'Album.private' => 0,
    )
));
```